# Select mailbox for Microsoft Outlook when using Applescript

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I'm using Applescript to automatically draft and send emails in Microsoft Outlook.  While everything is working as expected to send emails from my own account, I want to adjust the script to send emails from a different account that I have access to in Outlook.  I've found this post, but the approach shown there generates an error for me.

https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=185222#p185222

**How can I adjust the script below to select the correct mailbox to send my email from?** When I use the script below, the following error is generated when I attempt to save it.

> **Syntax Error**
> Expected class name but found identified

I've Google this error message, but haven't been able to find anything relevant to my task of changing the account the email is sent from.

```
set theAccount to the first exchange account whose name is "second.account@company.com"
set recipientAddress to "first.last@company.com"
set theSubject to "This is only a test"
set theContent to "<html><body><p>This is only a test.</p></body></html>"

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {account:theAccount, subject:theSubject, content:theContent}
    tell newMessage
        make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{address:recipientAddress}}
    end tell
    save in drafts
end tell
```

Comment: Your error message results from using an outlook term ('exchange account') outside of the outlook tell block. Move the 'tell application…' line to the very top and that error should cease. Note that the other three external lines can go anywhere as their focus is text but they may as well go inside the tell block too.

Comment: As to the accounts… when you specify account name then you must use the 'name' of the target account and not its 'email address' (unless they are the same, which is unlikely). You probably don't need the 'first whose name is' stuff unless you're doing something complicated. Instead, try `set xa2 to exchange account 2`.